# how to loop dropdownlist in a panel in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I just need to get the **selectedvalues** as well as **ID** for dropdownlist in a panel

how to loop dropdownlist in a panel in ASP.NET?

```
For i = 0 To pnl.Controls.Count - 1
                Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(pnl.Controls(i)., DropDownList)
                test = test & "[" & ddl.SelectedValue & "]"
 Next
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dropdown has an id it doesn't really matter if it is contained in another control. The C# code would look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    // Take whatever u want from the drop down, i.e:
    string string_name = string.Format("text: {0}, value: {1}", DropDownList1.Items[i].Text, DropDownList1.Items[i].Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
string selectedText = string.Empty;
int selectedId = -1;

if (DropDownList.SelectedItem != null)
{
   selectedText = DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
   selectedId = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

usually, you are binding the `id` as `value` of `DropDownList`

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop and since you already have your `DropDownList ddl` and can use the following `DropDownList` properties:

```
ddl.SelectedIndex //Index of selected item
ddl.SelectedValue //Value of selected item
ddl.ClientID  //Markup control ID
//wasn't sure ID meant Index or markup control ID
```

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx